# SQLServer Flat File Import: using Prose on more than 50 lines

Tags: sql-server

I use Microsoft SQLServer Flat File Import to create new tables from flat CSV files. The import tool (using Prose) establishes the column data types and lengths. However, it only uses the first 50 lines of the CSV for analysis, so it may miss longer varchar fields farther down in the file; which then will show up as errors during the import. Is it possible to change the value of 50 lines to a higher value (for instance: all lines of the CSV)?

Of course, through trial and error I can import long CSVs successfully, but this seems unnecessary.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server's inbuilt Import Wizard, then yes, you can define all the column types as you wish; the tool actually assumes all data types are text. This suggest that you are using a different tool other than SQL Server, and so you should be tagging that tool (my Google-Fu didn't give me much luck and the [[tag:prose]] tag doesn't appear to be related to data importing).

Comment: Prose is the technology used inside Microsoft SQLServer to analyse the CSV file in order to propose column data types and field lengths.

Comment: @Larnu PROSE = Program Synthesis using Examples, used in SQL Server 2022, ref: [Import Flat File to SQL Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-flat-file-wizard). Seems like another broken example of the data type sniffing used in the Excel drivers.